On the relative Weyl group
Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over a characteristic zero field $k$ and $T$ a maximal torus of $G$, $A\subset T$ a maximal $k$-split torus of $G$, the usual definition of the relative Weyl group for $G$ in the literature is
$$  W_{k}:=N_{G}(A)(k)/Z_{G}(A)(k)  $$, and it is known that this can be identified with the "combinatorial" Weyl group of the root system attached to $(G,A)$. Let's denote $W_{\overline{k}}:= N_{G}(T)/T(\overline{k})$ the absolute Weyl group of $G$.  If we denote $\mathfrak{a}:= X_{*}(A)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$, then there is a natural inclusion $W_{k}\hookrightarrow N_{W_{\overline{k}}}(\mathfrak{a})$ as we know the $W_{k}$-action on $X_{*}(T)$ preserves $X_{*}(A)$.
Is it true that $W_{k}=N_{W_{\overline{k}}}(\mathfrak{a})$ suppose $G$ is a quasisplit group over $k$? I manage to use the fact that for quasisplit group $G$ we have $Z_{G}(A)=T$.
